# Iterate through 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a "connect four board" which I simulate with a 2d array (array[x][y] x=x coordinate, y = y coordinate). I have to use  "System.out.println", so I have to iterate through the rows.

I need a way to iterate this way [0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [3,0] [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] etc

If i use the normal procedure:

```
for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++){
        string += array[i][j];
     } System.out.println(string)

}
```

it doesnt work because it iterates this way [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] etc

The normal procedure stays in x and increments y until the end of the column, but i need to say in y and increment x until the end of the row.

Comment: can the rows have different lengths?

Comment: Then use an array of size y*x, it would be more logical...

Comment: Use array[j][i].

Answer (score 42):

Consider it as an array of arrays and this will work for sure.

```
int mat[][] = { {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90},
                {15, 25, 35, 45},
                {27, 29, 37, 48},
                {32, 33, 39, 50, 51, 89},
              };


    for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<mat[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Values at arr["+i+"]["+j+"] is "+mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Just invert the indexes' order like this:

```java
for (int j = 0; j<array[0].length; j++){
     for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
```

because all rows has same amount of columns you can use this condition  j < array[0].lengt in first for condition due to the fact you are iterating over a matrix

Comment: ```because all rows has same amount of columns``` that might not be true. What if he uses ```new int[][] {{1,2,3},{4,5}};```?

Answer (score 8):

```
 //This is The easiest I can Imagine . 
 // You need to just change the order of Columns and rows , Yours is printing columns X rows and the solution is printing them rows X columns 
for(int rows=0;rows<array.length;rows++){
    for(int columns=0;columns <array[rows].length;columns++){
        System.out.print(array[rows][columns] + "\t" );}
    System.out.println();}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the indexes. i and j....in the loop, plus if you're dealing with Strings you have to use concat and initialize the variable to an empty Strong otherwise you'll get an exception.

```
String string="";
for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++){
        string = string.concat(array[j][i]);
    } 
}
System.out.println(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

These functions should work.

```
// First, cache your array dimensions so you don't have to
//  access them during each iteration of your for loops.
int rowLength = array.length,       // array width (# of columns)
    colLength = array[0].length;    // array height (# of rows)

//     This is your function:
// Prints array elements row by row
var rowString = "";
for(int x = 0; x < rowLength; x++){     // x is the column's index
    for(int y = 0; y < colLength; y++){ // y is the row's index
        rowString += array[x][y];
    } System.out.println(rowString)
}

//      This is the one you want:
// Prints array elements column by column
var colString = "";
for(int y = 0; y < colLength; y++){      // y is the row's index
    for(int x = 0; x < rowLength; x++){  // x is the column's index
        colString += array[x][y];
    } System.out.println(colString)
}
```

In the first block, the inner loop iterates over each item in the row before moving to the next column.

In the second block (the one you want), the inner loop iterates over all the columns before moving to the next row.

`tl;dr:` *Essentially, the* `for()` *loops in both functions are switched. That's it.*

I hope this helps you to understand the logic behind iterating over 2-dimensional arrays.

Also, this works whether you have a string[,] or string[][]

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea: get the lenght of the longest row, iterate over each column printing the content of a row if it has elements. The below code might have some off-by-one errors as it was coded in a simple text editor.

```
  int longestRow = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].length > longestRow) {
      longestRow = array[i].length;
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < longestRow; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[i].length > j) {
        System.out.println(array[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
//MREOW
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; j++) {
```