# Multiple while-loops for multidimensional array. Cumbersome, how to approach?

Tags: java, arrays

*Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate. The problem there is that for each row I need to search with findInLine, so each loop have a different parameter in findInLine.*

My code works in the following, however I don't think my code is effective or "good", due to many loops. 
I appreciate improvements.

I have this table:

```
00-01    Data11    Data12    Data13    Data14    
01-02    Data21    Data22    Data23    Data24    
02-03    Data31    Data32    Data33    Data34    
03-04    Data41    Data42    Data43    Data44    
04-05    Data51    Data52    Data53    Data54    
05-06    Data61    Data62    Data63    Data64    
06-07    Data71    Data72    Data73    Data74
```

I have an array int[7][4] data. I want to search for each row and save each column to the array. For example: search for `00-01`  and save the columns to the array:

```
data[0][0] = Data11
data[0][1] = Data12
data[0][2] = Data13
data[0][3] = Data14
```

And for `01-02`:

```
data[1][0] = Data21
data[1][1] = Data22
data[1][2] = Data23
data[1][3] = Data24
```

And so on for all rows.

**My approach:**

I use `findInLine` to find the row.

And for *each row* I use a while-loop, so for row `01-02` it is:

```
while (in.findInLine("01-02") == null)  in.nextLine();
in.nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < data[1].length; j++) {
        if (in.findInLine("-") !=null) 
            data[1][j] = 0;    // It is possible that an element of data in the table is marked "-", then set 0.
        else        
            data[1][j] =  Integer.parseInt(in.findInLine("[0-9]+|-"));
    in.nextLine();
}
    in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
```

And for printing *each row* I have in the main-method (here for `01-02`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
    System.out.print(data[1][i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

So finally I have the ouput for `01-02`:

```
Data21    Data22    Data23    Data24
```

And similar for, say, `03-04` I have:

```
while (in.findInLine("03-04") == null)  in.nextLine();
in.nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < data[3].length; j++) {
        if (in.findInLine("-") !=null) 
            data[3][j] = 0;    // It is possible that an element of data in the table is marked "-", then set 0.
        else        
            data[3][j] =  Integer.parseInt(in.findInLine("[0-9]+|-"));
    in.nextLine();
}
    in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
```

And printing `03-04`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data[3].length; i++) {
    System.out.print(data[3][i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

With the output:

```
Data41    Data42    Data43    Data44
```

And so on...

**My problem:**

With my approach I need 7 while-loops (one for each row) and 7 for-loops for printing. This feels cumbersome. Is it possible to solve in a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through 2 dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798958/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array)

Comment: Hi @Lino. I don't think it is a duplicate. The problem there is that for each row I need to search with findInLine, so each loop have a different parameter in findInLine.

Comment: From the example you've given, it seems that you could calculate `01-02` or any other string as they appear in linear order. E.g. hold a variable `int n = 0;` and then after each loop try to construct the next `String` for `findInLine`

Comment: Where do you get the data from? Is it stored in a database table, a csv file,...?

Comment: @Eritrean It's from a web page so html.

Comment: @JDoeDoe If it is html, you may take a look at [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) . Jsoup is an open source Java library used mainly for extracting data from HTML. It also allows you to manipulate and output HTML. It has great documentation and a fluent and flexible API. Jsoup can also be used to parse and build XML. If you can share the url of the page i can take a look and give you a starting example.