# How to print the first character in a two dimensional array

Tags: java

I am trying to print the first character of each word put into a two dimensional array. I get an error when I try to print it with a substring.

```
String [][] manyWords = { 
        {"red", "bling", "grand"},
        {"bridge", "queen", "chair"}
    };
    System.out.print(manyWords.substring(0, 1));
```

I get an uncompilable source code error.

Comment: `manywords` is any array.... substring() is a method on the String class......

Comment: You have to loop over the elements in the array. Arrays that contain objects are objects. The arrays themselves don't have the methods that the elements in the array have.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use some loops (I prefer for-each over for/while):

```
for(String[] strArr : manyWords){
   for(String str : strArr){
       System.out.println(str.substring(0,1);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should accomplish your goals:

```
    public class test{

      public static void main(String[] args){

    // Declare test array
    String [][] manyWords = { 
            {"red", "bling", "grand"},
            {"bridge", "queen", "chair"}
        };

    // Since it is a 2d array, loop through it with both an x and y coordinate
    // Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798958/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array for more info
    for (int i = 0; i < manyWords.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < manyWords[i].length; j++){

        // Set the current character using charAt
        char curr = manyWords[i][j].charAt(0);

        // Print it out
        System.out.println(curr);

      } //end inner for
    } //end outer for
  } //end psvm
} //end class
```

Prints:

```
r
b
g
b
q
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stream version:

```java
Stream.of(manyWords).flatMap(Stream::of).map(s -> s.substring(0, 1))
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. I hope this help you.

```
String [][] manyWords = { {"red", "bling", "grand"}, {"bridge", "queen", "chair"} };

for (int i = 0; i < manyWords.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < manyWords[i].length; j++) {
          System.out.print(manyWords[i][j].substring(0, 1) + " ");
   }
}
```