# How to write a method to find the average of a 4 by 3 dimensional array of doubles

Tags: java

I am trying to find the average of the 4 by 3 dimensional array but when I run the codes I receive and exception error. The thing is how to sum up the individual numbers in the array so I can find its average by dividing by its length.

Here is my code:

```
    double[][] numbers = {{1.1,2.2,1.3},{2.1,3.4,3.2},{5.4,6.5,3.7},{4.2,3.5,7.4}};
    double average = averagenum(numbers);
    System.out.println(average);
}

public static double averagenum(double[][] numbers) {
    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
        sum+= numbers[i][i+1];
        average = sum/numbers.length;
    }
    return average;
}
```

}

Comment: Take a pencil and some paper, write down a small valued 4x3 matrix on your paper, and then run through your function line by line, writing down what happens at each line. It'll take a minute or two, but you will almost immediately see what's going wrong when you get to the `sum += ...` line.

Comment: You can't loop in 2 dimensions at once, you need a separate inner `for` loop

Comment: If you're going to mention an error, please specify which error it is and where it occurs. Have you researched that error to see why it's thrown? What didn't you understand about that reason?

Comment: How do I separate it

Comment: The error was an exception

Comment: Also, please don't reask the exact same question. Edit it like you did to include additional details that were requested and wait for users to vote for it to be reopened.

Comment: Start with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798958/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array

Comment: Before beginning to implement anything in software, try to understand the real world issue, that your program is about. In this case: try to understand the mathematical concept of "average"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sure you can. for(i=0; i<n; i++){ sum += numbers[i/3][i%3]; } :D

Answer (score 0):

For a 2 dimensional array, you have to iterate through each loop and sum each element. Hence you can see 2 for loops to iterate through each dimension. I made a sum of each number and then divided by the product of each dimension

I guess you are looking for the following code.

```
public class CalculateAvg
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    double[][] numbers = { { 1.1, 2.2, 1.3 }, { 2.1, 3.4, 3.2 }, { 5.4, 6.5, 3.7 }, { 4.2, 3.5, 7.4 } };
    double average = averagenum(numbers);
    System.out.println(average);

  }

  public static double averagenum (double[][] numbers)
  {
    double totalAverage = 0.0d;
    double totalSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++)
      {
        totalSum += numbers[i][j];
      }
    }
    totalAverage = totalSum / (numbers.length*numbers[0].length);
    return totalAverage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Forgot to write the explanation. For a 2 dimensional array, you have to iterate through each loop and sum each element. Hence you can see 2 for loops to iterate through each dimension. I made a sum of each number and then divided by the product of each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment I was able to figure it out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] numbers = {{1.1,2.2,1.3},{2.1,3.4,3.2},{5.4,6.5,3.7},{4.2,3.5,7.4}};
        System.out.println("\tAverage:"+averagenum(numbers)+"\n");
        printer(numbers);
    }

    public static double averagenum(double[][] numbers) {
        double average = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int num = numbers.length * numbers[0].length;
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<numbers[0].length; j++){
                sum+= numbers[i][j];    
            }  
        }
        average = sum/num ;

        return average;
    }
    public static void printer(double[][] GenArray) {

        System.out.println("\tContent in Array:"+Arrays.deepToString(GenArray));
    }
}
```